# How to auto login (straight to desktop without any password)

Tags: greeter, security

I am currently downloading Loki and will be clean installing it tonight over Freya. This is my old parent's desktop. They get really irritated with logging in with a password. How do I do this? (Last time remember Freya forced me to generate a password.)

Answer (score 1):

In the `Settings` app there is a `User Accounts` panel, which contains a "Log In automatically" toggle:

[image: User Accounts]

Not sure whether the installer forces you to create a password, but it's important as a basic form of security.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the installer forces you to create a password but you can choose to login without entering a password on the login screen.

However, you will have to enter your password to install upgrades or do other system administration tasks.